# Deferred JQuery event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-deferred

I have a custom JQuery event like this `$element.trigger('customEvent1')`

Since the event handler might consist of user input (example like confirm dialog where user choose to proceed or abort), I need to wait for the event handler to finish. There might also be multiple event handler for this `customEvent1`.

How can I use deferred to wait for all event handler to finish?

So far I've tried this

```
$.when($element.trigger('customEvent1')).then(userActionCallback)
```

In the subscriber

```
$(document).on('customEvent1', '#element', function(evt) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   //user dialog Yes to resolve and No to reject
   return deferred.promise();
});
```

But it does not wait for the user input. Thanks for  your help.

For the note, the trigger and subscriber / event handler in not in the same document.

**Update 1**

As suggested I've tried this

```
$.when($element.triggerHandler('customEvent1')).then(userActionCallback);
```

For the Listener

```
$element.on('customEvent1', function(evt)
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   //user dialog Yes to resolve and No to reject
   return deferred.promise();
});
```

This works well. But how about if I'm using

```
$.when('customEvent1').then(userActionCallback);
```

How should I make the listener to be deferred?

Comment: The `trigger` method returns the current jQuery collection not the returned value of the event handler., ie. you are passing the `$element` object to `$.when` not the deferred object.

Comment: @undefined Do I need to use trigger `triggerHandler`? Or how can I make `trigger` deferred?

Comment: You can define a function which returns the deferred object. Why triggering an event? Yes, `triggerHandler` will return the deferred object. "Instead of returning the jQuery object (to allow chaining), `.triggerHandler()` returns whatever value was returned by the last handler it caused to be executed. If no handlers are triggered, it returns undefined"

Comment: Because the trigger is in a custom control JavaScript file and the subscriber is in their own JavaScript file. Otherwise I could have use a normal method / function

Comment: re `.triggerHandler()` - yes as *undefined* said. Probably not an issue here, but worth bearing in mind, "`.triggerHandler()` only affects the first matched element".

Comment: How about if I'm using `$.when('customEvent1').then(userActionCallback)`?

Comment: `$.when()` contains no magical powers to know when async code has finished.  Instead you have to pass it a promise object and then you have to make sure that that promise object is resolved when your async operation is completed.  None of your attempts so far are passing `$.when()` a promise object that gets resolved when your operation is done.  FYI, `.trigger()` returns the jQuery object, not whatever the event handler returned.